# Impala/Hive function to get the substring of a string

Tags: hive, impala

I am using regexp_extract for getting sub-string from a string

My string is ":abd: 576892034 :erg: 94856023MXCI :oute: A RF WERS YUT :oowpo: 649217349GBT GB"

How will get this using regexp_extract function.

I need 576892034 if i pass :abd:

Comment: any other function also fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT('your string', ':abd: ([^:]+)', 1)
```

The regexp `:abd: ([^:]+)` means match ':abd: ' folowed by any characters that are not ':'.

This regexp assumes that ':' does not appears withing the "value" strings. As such, it would fail on this input:

```
:abd: 5768:92034 :erg: 94856023MXCI :oute: A RF WERS YUT :oowpo: 649217349GBT GB
```